# URL dinámicas separadas por guión medio en php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy intentando crear URL dinámicas con htaccess con la siguiente estructura.

RewriteRule ^ruta1/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ ?variable1&key=$1 [L]

Para la variable 2, estoy poniendo los títulos de mis artículos para tener URLs  lo más dinámicas posibles. para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
<a href="ruta1/'.$variable1.'/'.urlencode($titulo).' ">Titulo</a>
```

**El problema del urlenconde es que me genera una estructura así:**
http://localhost/proyecto/ruta1/er57e65a34ffcb2e93cb545d024f5bde/Este+es+un+titulo+de+ejemplo

Y lo que yo necesito es negerar los títulos separados por "-" (guión medio):
http://localhost/proyecto/ruta1/er57e65a34ffcb2e93cb545d024f5bde/Este-es-un-titulo-de-ejemplo

La duda es: ¿Lo tendría que hacer con htacces o desde php al generar el título? y bueno está demás preguntar cual sería el procedimiento que necesitaría seguir.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno gracias de todas maneras ya logré solucionarlo. Pues resulta que la url la tengo que armar desde php, entonces el hipervínculo lo creo con una función a la que le envío el título y básicamente esa función me construye el título con la estructura que deseo. La función que hace la mágia es:str_replace();

```
 <a href="ruta1/'.$value1['ky'].'/'.tools::titulo($value['titulo']).' " 
 class="btn btn-primary">Hipervínculo</a>

  <?php class tools{ 
   public static function titulo($titulo,){
        $titulo  = urlencode(strtolower($titulo));
        $newtitulo = str_replace('+', '-', $titulo);
        return $newtitulo;
    }
  } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

El SEO que dicta Google recomienda el uso del guión medio `-` para cualquier enlace, link, url, etc.. De hecho, el guión bajo `_` quedó descontinuado desde hace aproximadamente 4 años y afecta el posicionamiento natural.

Comment: Podrías agregar el lugar de donde has leído esa sugerencia del SEO de Google o donde se sugiere eso?

Comment: De hecho Google recomienda lo contrario, como dice [aquí](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=es): _Recomendamos usar guiones (-) en lugar de guiones bajos (\_) en las URL._

Comment: Has dicho lo contrario en tu respuesta.